# sumif in multiple sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel file with one overview reconciliation sheet where all entities are listed and then a lot of other sheets where values are listed in column L and identification in column E. I would like to create a sumif function in reconciliation sheet where:

For all other than reconciliation sheet sum all rows in column L if value in column E equals to cell C56 in reconciliation sheet but only for those sheets in which cell B1 equals to the cell B5 in reconciliation sheet.

I would like it to be usable for all other sheets i will add.

Is something like that possible?

Thank you very much,

Martin

Comment: Look up `3d SUMIFS`

Comment: Could you post some sample data so we can see what you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Roughly my answer, in short, as under :

For Every Individual Sheet :

In F1 Give Heading as  "B1Ok"

In F2 Enter the Formula : =IF($B$1=Reconcile!$B$5,1,0)

In G1 Give Heading as  "C56Ok"

In G2 Enter the Formula : =IF(E2=Rconcile!$C$56,1,0)

In H1 Give the Heading as  "BothOk"

In H2 Enter the Formula : =AND(F2=1,G2=1)

Copy Paste F2,G2,H2 down the Line to get values

Now assuming that there are values in Column L from L2 to Say L100
Then in Cell L102 enter the Conditional Sumif Formula as Under :

=SUMIF(H2:H100,TRUE,L2:L100)

To get the desired sum.

I have answered as per my understanding.

I hope it may serve the purpose, if not fully, partially.

Revert back for any query.

Thanks.